# Integration of $1/(1-x^2)$ to prove $\operatorname{arctanh}(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Just for some background knowledge, I am doing this because I am trying to show that the derivative of arctanh(x) = $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$

How do I prove that the integral below is equal to arctanh(x)?

\begin{align}
\int{\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx}
\end{align}

So far, I managed to show that after integrating, it is equal to:

$$\\{\frac{1}{2}}\log\Bigl({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\Bigl)+C$$

And since we know that,

$$\operatorname{arctanh(x)}={\frac{1}{2}}\log\Bigl({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\Bigl)$$
How do I show that C = 0?

Comment: Indefinite integrals will always have a "+C". You cannot determine the value of C without an initial value.

Comment: I agree with David. The $C$ means that for any value of $C \in \mathbb{R}$, the function is an integral function of the integrand. Just set $C=0$ and you're done.

Comment: Why not $C\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but the question I was asked to do was to show that the derivative of arctanh(x) = 1/(1-x^2) using integration. If I can't show that both constants on each side are 0, how would I prove this?     In other words, how can I justify setting C=0?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that
$$
\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}
$$
then you can simply differentiate and find that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}
$$
because that's what the integral says.

---

You can also compute the derivative by using the definition, namely
$$
\tanh\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=x
$$
so by the chain rule
$$
1=(1-\tanh^2\operatorname{arctanh}(x))\operatorname{arctanh}'(x)
$$
and therefore
$$
\operatorname{arctanh}'(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}
$$
If you integrate the right-hand side, you find
$$
\int\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}+c
$$
and therefore $\operatorname{arctanh}(x)$ and this function differ by a constant
$$
\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}+c
$$
Evaluating at $0$ shows the constant is $0$.

Comment: I see that I missed the fact that when you integrate the differential of arctanh(x) you also get a constant C. So when I equate both sides of the equation with their respective constants I will get a new constant that will also equal 0. Is this correct?

Comment: @SmithH No. The two functions have the same derivative, so they differ by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Note that  you can directly show  $\operatorname{argtanh}x=\frac12\ln\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, by solving the equation
$$x=\tanh y=\frac{\mathrm e^{2y}-1}{\mathrm e^{2y}+1}\iff x(\mathrm e^{2y}+1)=\mathrm e^{2y}-1\iff \mathrm e^{2y}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}.$$
Also, you can easily get the derivative with the generic formula for the derivative of an inverse function:
$$\operatorname{argtanh}'(x)=\frac1{\tanh'(\operatorname{argtanh}x)}=\frac 1{1-\tanh^2(\operatorname{argtanh}x)}=\frac1{1-x^2}$$

Comment: That should be $(1+x)/(1-x)$, not its reciprocal.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Oops! Sorry, I typed this answer directy, without paper and pencil. 'Tis fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=0$ and since $\operatorname{arctanh} x=0$, then$$\begin{align*}\operatorname{arctanh}0 & =\frac 12\log\left(\frac {1+0}{1-0}\right)+C\\0 & =0 + C\end{align*}$$Thus $C=0$